# Convex hull in Ironpython

Tags: python, ironpython, convex-hull

I'm trying to get the convex hull from a list of points, this is based off of the Graham Scan method.

```
points = []
for element in elements:
    #getpoints function returns four corners of element bounding box with z overwritten to 0 so that we are working in 2D coordinates.
    for p in getPoints(element):
        points.append(p)
p0 = None
points.sort(key=lambda x: x.X)
points.sort(key=lambda x: x.Y)
#isolate lower left point
p0 = points.pop(0)
#sort by angle to x axis
points.sort(key=lambda x: DB.XYZ.BasisX.AngleTo(x-p0))
# We know the second point is correct, we are starting by checking the third point.
stack = [p0, points.pop(0), points.pop(1)]
while len(points) > 0:
    vector1 = stack[-2] - stack[-1]
    vector2 = points[0] - stack[-1]
    angle1 = math.atan2(vector1.X, vector1.Y)
    angle2 = math.atan2(vector2.X, vector2.Y)
    angleDiff = angle1 - angle2
    if angleDiff >= 0:
        stack.pop(-1)
        ######stack.append(points.pop(0))  I don't think this is needed, but it doesn't solve my problem when removed.
    else:
        stack.append(points.pop(0))
curves = []
for i, point in enumerate(stack):
    curves.append(DB.Line.CreateBound(point, stack[i-1]))
```

Output of "Convex Hull" which is clearly incorrect:

[image: Output of "Convex Hull" which is clearly incorrect.]

Edit for clarification:

Get the lowest point favoring leftmost.
Order all other points by their angle to the x axis.
Add the first three points to the stack.
Loop,
If the next sorted point would create an clockwise rotation, remove the top of the stack.
Else if it creates a counter clockwise rotation, add the candidate sorted point to the top of the stack.

I'll work on putting together a reproducible case.

YouTube link to explanation with graphic.

[Convex Hull Algorithm](https://youtu.be/B2AJoQSZf4M?t=72)

Desired Output:
[image: Desired Output:]

Comment: So... what is the question?

Comment: `stack = [p0, points.pop(0), points.pop(1)]` doesn't seem right; you're skipping a point, the one that was at `points[1]` before this statement (`pop(0)` moves that point to index 0, `pop(1)` then gets the point originally at index 2).

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  The supporting plot is a great help, but please supply a *simple* failing example, trace your point of error, and give us the output as a list of points, as well.

Comment: Please ad some *simple* test data that illustrates the problem.

Comment: To clarify: include some valid data that demonstrates the unexpected behavior. The data should be in a format such that somebody— using nothing other than the content of your post— will be able to use it as input to your program, and produce the same output. Also, your program should be runnable without any further modification (right now it is not runnable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rebuilt it in python and got it to work. I think the problem was in how I was calculating `angleDiff` where it would be easier to look at the sign of the cross product z value.

The `stack = [p0, points.pop(0), points.pop(1)]` would indeed skip a value, thanks jason.

I also have `vector1` backwards in the initial example. It should be `stack[-1] - stack[-2]`, **not** `stack[-2] - stack[-1]`

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import randint


class XYZ:
    @property 
    def X(self):
        return self._X
    @X.setter
    def X(self, X):
        self._X = X
    @property 
    def Y(self):
        return self._Y
    @Y.setter
    def Y(self, Y):
        self._X = Y

    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self._X = x
        self._Y = y

    def __add__(self, other):
        x = self.X + other.X
        y = self.Y + other.Y
        return XYZ(x, y)
    
    def __sub__(self, other):
        x = self.X - other.X
        y = self.Y - other.Y
        return XYZ(x, y)
    
    def ccw(self, other):
        return (self.X*other.Y - self.Y*other.X) > 0

### Rand Points
points = []
for i in range(100):
    points.append(XYZ(randint(0,100), randint(0,100)))
### Static Points
# points.append(XYZ(0,0))
# points.append(XYZ(0,1))
# points.append(XYZ(15,0))
# points.append(XYZ(0,6))
# points.append(XYZ(2,2))
# points.append(XYZ(0,8))
# points.append(XYZ(12,16))
# points.append(XYZ(12,2))
# points.append(XYZ(8,1))

for i, point in enumerate(points):
    plt.scatter([point.X], [point.Y])

points.sort(key=lambda x: x.X)
points.sort(key=lambda x: x.Y)
p0 = points.pop(0)
points.sort(key=lambda x: math.atan2((x-p0).Y, (x-p0).X))
stack = [p0]
stack.append(points.pop(0))
stack.append(points.pop(0))
while len(points) > 0:
    vector1 = stack[-1] - stack[-2]
    vector2 = points[0] - stack[-1]
    if not vector1.ccw(vector2):
        stack.pop(-1)
    else:
        stack.append(points.pop(0))

for i, point in enumerate(stack):
    plt.plot([point.X, stack[i-1].X], [point.Y, stack[i-1].Y])

plt.show()
```